# Watch service's variable from another module inside a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two modules "core" and "ui".

The ui module depends on core. This is the code for my core.js :

```
var core = angular.module('core', [ 'ngRoute' ]);

//Services
core.service('httpInformationService', function() {

    this.requestCount = 0;
    this.responseCount = 0;

    this.incrementRequest = function() {
        this.requestCount++;
        console.log('incrementRequest:' + this.requestCount);
    };

    this.incrementReponse = function() {
        this.responseCount++;
    }

    this.decrementRequest = function() {
        this.requestCount--;
        console.log('decrementRequest:' + this.requestCount);
    };

    this.decrementResponse = function() {
        responseCount--;
    }

    this.getRequestCount = function() {
        return requestCount;
    }

    this.getResponseCount = function() {
        return responseCount;
    }
});

//Service provider
core.provider("httpServiceInformationProvider", function() {
    var provider = {};

    provider.$get = ['httpInformationService', function( service ) {
        return service;
    }];

    return provider;
});

//HTTP Interceptor
core.factory('coreHttpInterceptor' ,function( httpInformationService ){
    var coreHttpInterceptor = {
        request: function(config) {
            httpInformationService.incrementRequest();
            return config;
        },
        response: function(response) {
            httpInformationService.decrementRequest();
            return response;
        }
    }

    return coreHttpInterceptor;
});


var config = {
    base_url: enviromnent_url,
}

core.value('config', config);

core.config(function( $interpolateProvider ) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol( "[[" ).endSymbol( "]]" );
});

core.config(function( $httpProvider ) {
   $httpProvider.interceptors.push('coreHttpInterceptor');
});
```

This is my ui.js code:

```
 var ui = angular.module('ui',[ 'core' , 'ui.bootstrap' ]);

ui.directive( "shLoadify" , function( httpServiceInformationProvider ){
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind( "click", function() {
                element.text("Loading...");
                element.prop( "disabled", true );
            });
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.$watch('httpServiceInformationProvider', function(oldValue, newValue){
                console.log(oldValue + ' ' + newValue);
            }, true);
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see i am trying to access requestCount property of httpInfomationService from within my controller using $scope.watch.

The problem is newValue and oldValue is always null. Why is that so?

Comment: You are watching `$scope.httpInfomationService ` and it is undefined

Comment: When i try to log it, it is not.

Comment: no, you are logging something inside a service. where do you put this in your scope?

Comment: You are trying to watch the $scope.httpServiceInformationProvider. Try one one the following codes and see if when you change the httpServiceInformationProvider the watcher triggers `$scope.$watch(httpServiceInformationProvider,function(....` or `$scope.$watch(function(){return httpServiceInformationProvider;},function(....`. Also are you expecting to the service to change or a value in the service to change?

Comment: Im expecting a value in the service to change. I already logged httpServiceInformationProvider.requestCount but still I got undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach 1**

If you want to perform some action whenever your `requestCount` variable gets changed which is part of service, you need to `broadcast/emit` which then you can listen through `on`. But in this case you need to pass the scope in your service which is not recommended.

```
var app = angular.module('app',['app1']);

app.service('myService',function($rootScope){
  this.requestCount=1
  this.incrementRequestCount=function(){ 
    this.requestCount++
    $rootScope.$broadcast('requestCountChanged', { message: this.requestCount });
  }.bind(this)

})


app.controller('myController',['$scope','myService',function($scope,myService){

  $scope.$on('requestCountChanged', function(event, args) {
      // You will find the updated requestCount in args
    }); 

   $scope.click= myService.incrementRequestCount;

}])

var app1 = angular.module('app1',[]);
    app1.controller('mySecondController',['$scope','myService',function($scope,myService){

      $scope.$on('requestCountChanged', function(event, args) {
            // You will find the updated requestCount in args
        }); 

    }])
```

**Approach 2**

Without passing scope in the service

```
var app = angular.module('app',['app1']);

app.service('myService',function(){
  this.requestCount=1
  this.incrementRequestCount=function(){ 
    debugger;
    this.requestCount++
  }.bind(this)

})


app.controller('myController',['$scope','myService','$rootScope',function($scope,myService,$rootScope){

   $scope.click=function(){
     myService.incrementRequestCount();
     $rootScope.$broadcast('requestCountChanged', { message: myService.requestCount });

   }  

}])

var app1 = angular.module('app1',[]);
    app1.controller('mySecondController',['$scope','myService',function($scope,myService){

      $scope.$on('requestCountChanged', function(event, args) {

            // You will find the updated requestCount in args
        }); 

    }])
```

**Approach 3**

You can only attach watch to those properties which are actually in the scope otherwise you cannot have watch for those properties. So just add `requestCount`  on you scope than you can easily detect its changes using watch and then use broadcast/emit approach.

```
var app = angular.module('app',['app1']);

app.service('myService',function(){
  this.requestCount=1
  this.incrementRequestCount=function(){ 
    debugger;
    this.requestCount++
  }.bind(this)

})


app.controller('myController',['$scope','myService','$rootScope',function($scope,myService,$rootScope){

    $scope.requestCount=myService.requestCount
    $scope.$watch('requestCount',function(n,o){
      debugger;
      if(n!=o)
      {
          $rootScope.$broadcast('requestCountChanged', { message: n });
      }
    })
   $scope.click=function(){
     myService.incrementRequestCount();
     $scope.requestCount=myService.requestCount


   }  

}])

var app1 = angular.module('app1',[]);
    app1.controller('mySecondController',['$scope','myService',function($scope,myService){

      $scope.$on('requestCountChanged', function(event, args) {

            // You will find the updated requestCount in args
        }); 

    }])
```

Comment: can you provide fiddle for this? Thank you =)

Comment: Just edited my post with some code for your reference.